# another quick way to mimic or use onload for div

Tags: php, javascript

I want to automatically get the comments, and i need help trying to mimic or use onload with a div tag.

```
 echo <div id='comments".$roow['ID']."' onload='getcomments($roow[ID])'></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a script element immediately following the div, it should not be executed until the div has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Well a div does not have onload event so your example will not work. Guessing you already found that out.

Try just calling window.onload on the page and looking for elements with a certain class. Than loop through and make your calls.

Comment: There is no current W3C standard that requires div elements to support the load event, however HTML5 defines an *onload* attribute for the [HTMLElement interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlelement) that div elements should implement, so it may become a (more or less) standard feature in future.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break this solution into 2 parts

- For all `div` elelements that need to load comments give them a specific class say `commentOnLoad`
- Have a script which runs on document load that loads comments for `div` elements of that class

PHP

```
echo <div id='comments".$roow['ID']."' class="commentOnLoad"> ... </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.commentOnLoad').each(function() {
     // Strip off the 'comments' prefix
    var roowId = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);
    getcommens(roowId);
  });
});
```

Javascript

```
var onLoad = function() {
  var elem;
  for (elem in document.getElementsByClass('commentOnLoad')) {
    // Strip off the 'comments' prefix
    var roowId = elem.getAttribute('id').substring(8);
    getcommens(roowId);
  }
};
```

Comment: how would i implement this  raw js?

Comment: @mayank23 added a raw js sample. The method would need to be called from your load handler